Is there a way to differentiate between new purchase and old purchases in auto renewal subscription in swift?
Is there any way to recognise new purchase in below delegate in swift?
 func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            hideLoader()
            if let transactionID = transaction.transactionIdentifier {
                print("Transaction ID: \(transactionID)")
                SubscriptionViewController.store.complete(transaction: transaction)
                // updateUserStatus(subscriptionType: currentSubscription)
                validateReceipt(transId: transaction.transactionIdentifier ?? "") // after verify also update on backend
            }
            break
        case .failed:
            self.currentSubscription = nil
            hideLoader()
            SubscriptionViewController.store.fail(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .restored:
            hideLoader()
            break
        case .deferred:
            hideLoader()
            break
        case .purchasing:
            break
        @unknown default:
            hideLoader()
            print("Unknown case happens")
            break
        }
    }
 }

I am facing this problem when I already have an active membership and when I tap on buy it again, it shows me you had already an active subscription, which is correct.
It then prompts for two options which is manage or ok, and when I tap on ok my above delegate is called and goes into Purchased state again.  The above delegate is also called when I purchase a new product.
I want to distinguish this for only new purchases, because I need to update to server, can anyone tell me how can we check new purchase only in updatedTransactions method?

It is better to detect that the user has a current subscription before allowing them to attempt to purchase

There is no way to sell same auto renewable subscription product for a user. However, if you organize your business logic, then you can sell diffrent auto renewable subscription products.
The transactionId that you use, changes every purchase process. So you can't compare previous subscription with new purchase. You should use originalTransactionId. The originalTransactionId is unique for a auto-renewable subscription product and a purchase. You should save it on a server and during the second subscription purchase, can check it with the originalTransactionId from the server.
Referanced from;
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/originaltransactionid
